# How to validate for existing account on login click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a login form and clicking the login button invokes the following method:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccountBLL accBLL = new AccountBLL();

        string username = tbUsername.Text;
        string password = accBLL.getAccount(username).Password;

        if (tbPassword.Text == password)
        {
            // Authenticate user
            string role = accBLL.getAccount(username).Role;

            // Create Form Authentication Ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, role);

            // Encrypt the ticket
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            // Create cookie
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            // Add cookie to outgoing cookie collection
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            // Redirect to the URL
            if (role == "admin")
                Response.Redirect("AdminHome.aspx");
            else if (role == "user")
                Response.Redirect("UserHome.aspx");
            else
                lblMsg.Text = "Invalid login!";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Invalid password.";
        }

        //string accountID = (Session["AccountID"]).ToString();
    }
```

However, if the account doesn't exist/is not created yet I will get a null pointer error on `string password = accBLL.getAccount(username).Password;` because the username passed in to to the `getAccount()` method doesn't exist. So my question is, how should I edit the code to implement some sort of validation, should the event that the userid passed in to retrieve the password is non existent, an error message would be displayed to the user instead?

Comment: @stakx I only get the error when the account record doesn't exist! my bad, didn't phrase it properly

Comment: Plain text password storage?  Evil... if anyone attacks your site, they can use your user list to attack your users on other sites.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Ahaha yup planning on doing something about that! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your GetAccount method compare for null
like 
fill dt
and compare dt

```
if (dt.rows.count==0)
{
return null;
}
```

this will return null value if account is not created yet.
    and then your login button click event will look like this.

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AccountBLL accBLL = new AccountBLL();

            string username = tbUsername.Text;
            string password = accBLL.getAccount(username).Password;
            if(password != null)
    {
            if (tbPassword.Text == password)
            {
                // Authenticate user
                string role = accBLL.getAccount(username).Role;

                // Create Form Authentication Ticket
              ..... your remaining code including else

    }
    else 
    {
    lblMsg.Text = "Account Doesnt Exist";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've said it yourself that the method getAccount returns null when the provided username does not exist. If I were you I would check if accBLL.getAccount(username) returns a null. If it does, I would not execute the rest of the code and instead display a label with a message to the user that the enterd username does not exist.

First check if the username exists, and if it does, then check if the password is correct.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Change these lines

```
string password = accBLL.getAccount(username).Password;
if (tbPassword.Text == password)
```

to this.

```
var account == accBLL.getAccount(username);
if (account != null && tbPassword.Text == account.Password)
```